# Vertical Flyout menu with pure CSS

Tags: html, css

Please check the below code..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">      
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title>hover-navigation</title>

        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="yesvin">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0">

        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">

        <style>
            html, body {
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            .menuContainer{
                width:100px;
                height:100vh;
                background:#ccc;
                z-index:1;                  
            }
            .menuContainer ul {
                padding:20px 0 0 0;
                margin:0;   
            }
            .menuContainer ul li {
                padding:10px;
                margin:0;
                list-style: none;               
                border-bottom:solid 1px #000;
                font-family:'Arial';
                font-size:16px;
                background:#00ACD6;
                position: relative;
            }
            .menuContainer ul li:hover{             
                background:#00A65A;
                cursor:pointer;
            }
            .menuContainer ul li a{
                text-decoration:none;               
                color:#000;             
            }
            .menuContainer ul li:hover a{
                text-decoration:none;               
                color:#fff;
            }
            .menuContainer ul li a:after{
                content:' •'    
            }

            .menuContainer ul li ul {               
                position: absolute;             
                top:-20px;
                left:-100px;
                height:100vh;
                width:0px;
                z-index:-1;

                -webkit-transition: width 0.4s, left 0.4s;
                -o-transition: width 0.4s, left 0.4s;
                transition: width 0.4s, left 0.4s;
            }
            .menuContainer ul li:hover ul {             
                left:100px;
                width:100px;    
            }
        </style>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="menuContainer">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Frontend</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>HTML</li>
                        <li>CSS</li>
                        <li>Javascript</li>
                    </ul>                   
                </li>                                   
                <li><a href="#">Backend</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>PHP</li>
                        <li>MYSQL</li>
                        <li>ASP</li>
                        <li>JSP</li>                        
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here the problem is with 'z-index'. Because of that when i hover the 'li' the sub-menu opens, but it hides, when i mouse over the next 'li'

But removing the 'z-index' or maintaining same 'z-index' for both 'container' and 'ul li ul' works fine. But sub-menu animate over the main menu.

I need sub-menu should come behind the container. What will be the workaround for this...

Checkout the fiddle for a demo http://jsfiddle.net/a92c03zj/1/

Thanks in advance ...

Comment: these fly out menus are a bit early 2000s don't you think

Comment: Yes..i know Its old one. But need to fix the existing project. So that i don't want to change the entire code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this out:

```
.menuContainer ul li ul {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    top:-20px;
    left:100px;
    height:100vh;
    width:0px;
    z-index:0;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.4s;
    -o-transition: width 0.4s;
    transition: width 0.4s;
}
.menuContainer ul li:hover ul {
    width:100px;
    z-index:1;
}
```

Just change these lines of code with yours and it should work as you wanted. For your explanation: Instead of animating the left position(which we can't really see anyways) we just animate the width. For the text to display nicely throughout the whole time, we use "`overflow:hidden`" so that the text is not being clinched. Also, as we now just animate the width, the left position is initially set to 100px. The last change I made was to change the z-index on hover, so that the "old" dropdown is not being animated on top of the "new" one.

Comment: Hi Frederik it is working as expected. Thank you for your help.